# Why this C++ program crashes specifically when run through command prompt on multiple files but not when run on individual files?

Tags: c++, string, command-prompt, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int main() {
  string xs;
  string* atom=new string[60000];
  string* aa=new string[60000];
  string* pos=new string[60000];
  string* aaid=new string[60000];
  string* chain=new string[60000];
  string* X=new string[60000];
  string* Y=new string[60000];
  string* Z=new string[60000];
  string* occupancy=new string[60000];
  string* bfactor=new string[60000]; 
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open ("1ASO.pdb"); //similar to 1ASO.txt
  //middle codes
  delete [] atom;
  delete [] aa;
  delete [] pos;
  delete [] aaid;
  delete [] chain;
  delete [] X;
  delete [] Y;
  delete [] Z;
  delete [] occupancy;
  delete [] bfactor;
  inFile.close();
}
```

This code works fine, but when I changed it to take input of files through command prompt as shown below, it crashes for specific files like 1ASO.pdb. I used the following command in command prompt to run the program for all pdb files.
for %f in (*.pdb) do prog "%f"
My guess is I'm doing dynamic memory allocation wrong but not sure how to fix it.

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   string xs;
   string* atom=new string[60000];
   string* aa=new string[60000];
   string* pos=new string[60000];
   string* aaid=new string[60000];
   string* chain=new string[60000];
   string* X=new string[60000];
   string* Y=new string[60000];
   string* Z=new string[60000];
   string* occupancy=new string[60000];
   string* bfactor=new string[60000]; 
   ifstream inFile;
   inFile.open (argv[1]); //similar to 1ASO.txt
   //middle codes
   delete [] atom;
   delete [] aa;
   delete [] pos;
   delete [] aaid;
   delete [] chain;
   delete [] X;
   delete [] Y;
   delete [] Z;
   delete [] occupancy;
   delete [] bfactor;
   inFile.close();
 }
```

Comment: You're allocating six hundred thousand string objects.  I can't help but think this isn't your intent.

Comment: Your program will most probably crash also on that specific file if run inividually. Find that file and debug. The crash is in your 'middle codes' but the shown code suggests that there is design problem as well (60.000 strings? no structs?)

Comment: Yes, pdb files have specific format in which coordinates of atoms are written. I used string to extract those characters into those string arrays. Now some of the pdb files are quite large having 40-50k atoms. I wasn't able to declare local arrays of size more than 25000 for each variable. The thing is 1ASO is one of those file and it works when run individually but crashes when run on multiple files through command prompt. The program works very well for all the files individually.

Comment: did you try to attach a debugger or analyse crash dumps?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a special reason why you are allocating all these strings? Why don't you just declare them as local variables?

Have you looked at what argv[1] is? Are you sure it is the name of the file you want?

Comment: Yes, pdb files have specific format in which coordinates of atoms are written. I used string to extract those characters into those string arrays. Now some of the pdb files are quite large having 40-50k atoms. I wasn't able to declare local arrays of size more than 25000 for each variable.

Comment: argv[1] is the file name. I'm sure and have verified it.